# .htaccess redirection rules with parameter rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Which redirects every server/path request to server/path.php file.

I want to add one more specific rule, to redirect everything of the form /item/id to /item.php?var=id

Can I make it work together?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?var=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: almost, in the case of /item/1 it will redirect to /item.php?id=1.php

Comment: I've mistakenly wrote the id instead of var please try the edit.

Comment: Well I am rewriting instead of redirecting do you want a redirect because I assumed you want a rewrite observed by your current rule.

Comment: The /item/number case is a special case where I need a redirection of the form /item.php?id=number on all other case, request for /word should go to /word.php

Comment: I am confused pal, you are using the rewrite rule in your current .htaccess but talking about redirecting did you give it a try?

Comment: you redirect the request /item/1 to /item.php?var=1.php ... should be /item.php?var=1 instead

Comment: So it is appending .php in the end you are saying, try it here it is working http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c536c075-9b30-513a-8d1f-e6c3a07f4e02 as expected. make sure no other rule is conflicting.